# Count rows which are more than once and twice by one query

Tags: mysql

I have a table similar to: (There are actually many more rows.)

```
   user_id   |     text  
---------------------------    
      1      |      a
      1      |      b
      2      |      c
      3      |      d
      3      |      e
      4      |      f
      4      |      g
      4      |      h
      4      |      i
      5      |      j
      5      |      k
      5      |      l
      6      |      m
```

I want to know how many users appeared more than once, and how many users appeared more than twice among them.((4, 2) for above table)

Now I'm using this query, but I have to run it two times after changing the number to 2.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT NULL
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) T1
```

Because table is so big, it takes a lot of time. Can I handle these two cases in one Query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in one query by summing the counts:

```
SELECT SUM(count > 1) AS more_than_once,
       SUM(count > 2) AS more_than_twice
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
      FROM my_table
      GROUP BY user_id
      HAVING count > 1) t
```

Output:

```
more_than_once  more_than_twice
4               2
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oJsUy2ptsr43m4ghq8Z6wF/0)

Answer (score 0):

try like this mate

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT NULL
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) T1 WHERE COUNT(*) > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(v.gt1)  AS cnt_gt_1
     , SUM(v.eq3)  AS cnt_eq_2
     , SUM(v.gt2)  AS cnt_gt_2
  FROM ( SELECT COUNT(*) > 1 AS gt1
              , COUNT(*) = 2 AS eq2
              , COUNT(*) > 2 AS gt2 
           FROM mytable t
          GROUP 
             BY t.user_id 
         HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
       ) v
```

For performance of the inline view query, we want an index with user_id as the leading column... e.g.

```
   ... ON my_table (user_id)
```